# SmarterMail 8.4 with Outlook 2010 using POP3, some mail not downloaded

Tags: outlook, webmail

We have a very strange situation.
We are subscribe to SmarterMail 8.4 for hosting our email services, the email hosting panel is WebsitePanel + Plesk Panel.

Our colleague is using Outlook 2010 with POP3 setting.

We had noticed that some of the mail was found in the webmail, but it is not found in the Outlook client. The webmail got 50 emails showed, but outlook only showed 42 emails, it from different sender also.

Thing for sure,
- My colleague did not delete the email.

It is just not downloaded to the outlook client,

What will be the possibility reason that will happen? As my understanding is if Webmail do exist the email, it will download to outlook.

We email to support, they had response that

> We unable to assist you as this Outlook issue as we didn't support for
>   technical issue on Outlook. Since the email already been received in
>   the webmail, so there is no issue on our side.

NOT all my colleague having this issue, only 2-3 out of 10 people, this is why make us headache.

Please assist. Thanks!

Comment: Well I think you have your answer - Outlook is unsupported by your email provider.

Comment: But not all my colleague having this issue, only 2-3 out of 10 people, how can you explain this?

Comment: As I search in the SmarterMail knowledge base website, they do support POP3, http://portal.smartertools.com/KB/a1555/configure-outlook-2010-imap-or-pop-account.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After we investigate about this issue, we found out that, this 2-3 user profile config setting got corrupted before. On the server side, they do help us to restore the user profile.

Another possible reason is our bad connection issue, this might be the reason as well, but not sure after with good connection, the email should be downloaded but it fail to.

We had decided switch to another more reliable hosting to get out this kind of problem.

Thank you very one answer. I knew this kind of issue, sometimes don't have 100% solution. Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0):

try move those emails which are not shown on the outlook to a separate folder on the webmail and then configure a IMAP on your outlook and see if those mails can be downloaded.

The other thing you could try is to recreate a new profile for your outlook and see if those mails could be downloaded, it may be the existing outlook profile has been corrupted.

Comment: Now we actually know there is a mail missing, then we can retrieve from the webmail. The problem now is our management want us to give a reason that why this thing will happen to particular user only. We had ask our colleague to check their webmail offen. Not dare to depending on outlook anymore...